# Se puede hacer un INNER JOIN con un WHERE?

Tags: php, sql

Me da error , es un error de formulación seguro, pero no lo encuentro

```
SELECT * FROM comentariosforo WHERE ID_Post = '$IDPost'
INNER JOIN usuarios
ON usuarios.ID = comentariosforo.ID_Persona
```

Comment: el where ponelo al final, "seleccionar tal cosa de tal tabla juntandola con la tabla tal haciendo coincidir este y este campo, donde (ademas) tal campo sea tal valor"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te pongo el siguiente ejemplo para que lo adaptes según tus necesidades.

Imagina que tengo 2 tablas; una llamada usuarios y otra llamada posts, donde guardo el id del usuario que hizo cada posts; entonces al final quiero con un JOIN obtener todos los posts que le corresponden al usuario con id 3

```
SELECT title, body, username 
FROM usuarios
INNER JOIN posts
ON usuarios.id = posts.usuario_id
WHERE usuarios.id = $usuario_id;
```

> Como notas si hago uso del WHERE pero al final de la consulta, pues
>   primero necesita realizar el JOIN así como indicarle en que campo en
>   especifico se cumple la unión de ambas tablas